# How to make JSPM install Bower dependencies

Tags: bower, jspm

For a while now, my client has been using some Node and Bower components to build projects. Whenever a new developer comes in, it's easy for that person to simply run

```
npm install
bower install
```

And then be ready to work.

We are working on a new project and this time we want to use JSPM instead of Bower. However, we want to leverage our existing private libraries (20+ of them) and we don't want to spend stupid amounts of time rewriting them. Plus they still need to work as regular Bower components for other projects.

So far, this worked. We used jspm-git to set the registry. However, JSPM fails in one regards: it does not install the Bower dependencies of those libraries it installed.

How would we go about that? I would love the other devs in the team to be able to check out the project and run

```
npm install
jspm install
```

And be on their way. It doesn't seem possible so far. Any set up we have forgotten? Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know little about `jspm` but from my experience `npm` is quite fine for getting dependencies for both, server and client code. If you use tool such as `webpack`, it will then analyze, what exactly are you using from your `node_modules` directory and compile one or more bundles you can require from client-side. What more can one want?

Answer (score 1):

You need the jspm bower endpoint:
npm install jspm-bower-endpoint --save-dev

Then you need to register the bower endpoint with jspm:
jspm registry create bower jspm-bower-endpoint

Then you can install bower packages:
jspm install bower:angular-bootstrap-multiselect

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Just installed it successfully with `jspm install npm:bootswatch`, then required it in code with `<require from="bootswatch/slate/bootstrap.min.css"></require>`

Also posted this info on the bootswatch-dist project on github here: https://github.com/dbtek/bootswatch-dist/issues/32